# All rss feeds (tags and user feeds) are misconfigured

Tags: bug, rss

I am using `firefox` 14. Whenever I open my normal `askubuntu` user feed (and my `meta` one, although that is blank anyway until I post this question), it opens up a download box instead of displaying it in a new tab; when I open the downloaded file in `firefox` (after adding the `.xhtml` suffix) it comes up with:

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
```

When I try to add mine or anyone else's feed to `Thunderbird`, I get a message relating to an invalid feed.

When I try to validate my user feed at `w3.org`, I get the following:

```
This feed does not validate.
    line 2, column 0: XML parsing error: <unknown>:2:0: XML or text declaration not at start of entity [help]
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Source: http://askubuntu.com/feeds/user/76204
```

This problem has been going on for several days now and I think it's the same for everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested the feeds now and they seem fine again, but they were appearing as **invalid** for the last 2-3 days.

I think the issue is solved now, so I'll mark it as such. If it happens again we can reopen it.